# ReportLab Wrap with drawstring

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab

I am new to report lab and python. I know with reportlab you can wrap test in paragraphs and Tables but I am drawing a report with variable text and sometimes the text is two long and needs to be wrapped. Is there a way to allow the text send to drawstring in reportlab to be wrapped if it is too long ?

System Info: 
Windows 8 machine, ReportLab 3.3, Python 3

Answer (score 10):

It looks like drawstring does not allow for wrapping. I ended up solving the problem by using the textwrap python function; that will split the original string into a list and then take the result of the list and manually creating a new line with drawstring if it passes certain length.

```
import textwrap



 if len(originalstring) > 45:
        wrap_text = textwrap.wrap(originalstring, width=45)
        canvas.drawString(coordx, coordy, wrap_text[0])
        canvas.drawString(coordx, coordy, wrap_text[1])
  else:
        canvas.drawString(coordx, coordy, originalstring)
```

Comment: On Stackoverflow, you should upvote *any* questions or answers you find useful.  And on your questions, if one of the answers is a good fit for your problem, you can mark it as the accepted answer.  See the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for guidelines.  This even applies when you answer your own question.